# how to connect iphone with monitor?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented iphone application.i want to present in monitor.How it possible?
Please help me for this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad VGA Connector - Mirror screen in own Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662201/ipad-vga-connector-mirror-screen-in-own-application)

Answer (score 0):

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1454